# Regex pattern for zip codes and extras

Tags: regex

I would like to create pattern for zip-codes in Poland.
Basic pattern is:

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}
```

but i also want to add extra recognize for characters like: `+,/,u`
from input: `21-378+854-4353u654645-34534`
i would like to recieve `21-378+54-435u45-345`
I tried severall ways but i only have: `21-378+54-43545-345`

Comment: Show us what you tried (code?)

Comment: We take tags seriously here at Stack Overflow.  Please do not tag languages (like `java`) which have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Can you clarify your question (use [edit] option for that)? How do you recognize that `21-378+854-4353u654645-34534` should return `21-378+54-435u45-345`?

Comment: What does "*extra recognize*" mean in your case?

Comment: I don't understand the logical leap from the input (`21-378+854-4353u654645-34534`) to the output (`21-378+54-435u45-345`).  What rules apply?

Comment: It's <zipcode1><somestuff><zipcode2><somemorestuff><zipcode3><yetmorestuff>

Comment: Sorry for that, my first post on stack, I made java tag because i implement that soultion in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still doesn't make much sense to me, but how about this regex?

```
/[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}|[+u\/]/g
```

The trick is that you add `|[+u\/]` which allows for an "or" expression if the pattern isn't found.  The `[]` part is a character class that allows you to only match the "+", "u", and "/" characters.  "/" is escaped with `\`.

Here it is implemented in javascript

```js
var test = "21-378+854-4353u654645-34534";
var pattern = /[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}|[+u\/]/g;
console.log(test.match(pattern).join(''));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to make for example union where I have '+'